# DropzoneJS with div table layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropzone.js

**The general question:**

How can I get the added row in my Dropzone to fill the full width of the table when it's by default being wrapped in an element that ruins my table layout.

**Explanation:**

I'm trying to get DropzoneJS to show uploaded files in a table format. My Dropzone is correctly on my table but I can't get the previewTemplate to present properly.
First of all, the issue arises because Dropzone cannot add files to a `<td></td>` element, so I converted my table to a table layout format like this using CSS

```
<div class="div-tr">
    <div class="div-td"></div>
    <div class="div-td"></div>
</div>
```

My goal is therefore to add a previewTemplate to DropzoneJS which would look like this

```
<div class="div-tr">
    <div class="div-td">
        <i class="fa fa-file-o"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="div-td">
        <div class="dz-filename">
            <span data-dz-name></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-td">
        <div class="dz-size" data-dz-size></div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-td">
        <div class="dz-progress">
            <span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-td">
        <div class="dz-success-mark">
            <span>✔</span>
        </div>  
        <div class="dz-error-mark">
            <span>✘</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that Dropzone by default adds a set of classes `dz-processing dz-image-preview dz-error dz-success` to a `<div>` in the previewTemplate. According to the docs, they will be added to a `<div>` with `class="dz-preview"`, but no matter whether that class exists or not the other classes are added as the first inner element of the container, that previewTemplate is injected in. 
This means that the previewTemplate, which was supposed to be a table row, loses it's properties and now only shows in the width of the first `<div class="div-td">`

```
+-------------+--------------+-----------+----------+
|             |              |           |          |   Existing row
+-------------+--------------+-----------+----------+
|             |              |           |          |   Existing row
+-------------+--------------+-----------+----------+
|             |              |           |          |   Existing row
+-------------+--------------+-----------+----------+
|             |              |           |          |   Existing row
+-------------+--------------+-----------+----------+
|   |   |  |  |                                         Row added by upload
+---+---+--+--+
```

This happens because there is an extra `<div>` being added that wraps the inner of the row.

My CSS for the table looks like this

```
/* DIV table style */

.div-table{
     display: table;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: #fff;
}
.div-tr{
    display: table-row;
}
.div-th, .div-td {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeff0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.div-thead{
    display: table-header-group;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.div-tfoot{
    display: table-footer-group;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.div-tbody{
    display: table-row-group;
}
```

Documentation for the layout is found here: http://www.dropzonejs.com/#layout

Any help for changing the CSS or JS is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the dropzone documentation you can customize the preview template as you wish, in this case you just need to add your `div-tr` and `div-td` classes to the preview elements according to your needs, http://www.dropzonejs.com/#theming.

Here is an example of how override the dropzone template:

Html:

```
<div class="dropzone" id="myDropzone"></div>

    <div class="dropzone-previews div-table"></div>

    <div id="preview-template" style="display: none;">
        <div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview div-tr">
            <div class="dz-details">
                <div class="dz-filename div-td"><span data-dz-name></span></div>
                <div class="dz-size div-td" data-dz-size></div>
                <div class="dz-image div-td">
                    <img data-dz-thumbnail />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dz-progress div-td"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress></span></div>
            <div class="div-td">
                <div class="dz-success-mark"><span>✔</span></div>
                <div class="dz-error-mark"><span>✘</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="dz-error-message div-td"><span data-dz-errormessage></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

js:

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    previewsContainer: ".dropzone-previews",
    previewTemplate: document.getElementById('preview-template').innerHTML,
    url: 'upload.php',
    init: function() {
        this.on('success', function(file){
            var errordiv = document.getElementsByClassName('dz-error-mark');
            errordiv[errordiv.length - 2].style.display = 'none'; // The -2 is because there is also one in the preview-template
        });
        this.on('error', function(file){
            var succesdiv = document.getElementsByClassName('dz-success-mark');
            succesdiv[succesdiv.length - 2].style.display = 'none'; 
        });
    }
}
```

Note that if you want to use a table you can by just wrapping the elements in the preview with `<td>` and `<tr>` and use as `previewsContainer` a table instead of a div.

Because the elements `dz-error-mark` and `dz-success-mark` are always visible in dropzone by default, you may want to hide them accordingly to the events, this is what does the code inside the init function. Or maybe is better to not display them at the beginning and show them accordingly.

Have in mind that as you make changes in the template, things are going to start not displaying properly if you don't modify also the default behavior of dropzone.

[Here](http://www.dropzonejs.com/bootstrap.html) you can see an example of a heavily customized dropzone, also mentioned in the dropzone documentation.

Comment: I already tried everything you are suggesting as well as gone through all those links. I originally had the whole thing as a table with real table elements, but then after using it as a Bower dependency, I got this error `dropzone.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: a.previewElement.querySelectorAll is not a function`. I investigated that and found that everybody was writing that it couldn't be table elements.
If I use the JS example you posted, then I get that `innerHTML is undefined`, which I guess is because it's an Angular app. Do you have tips to why these things occur? I'll investigate more.

Comment: It was `TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null` when I add the InnerHTML statement, and I see that it's because the DOM is then not loaded at the time of instantiation. I tried fixing this with $timeout and similar which solves that, but I keep getting further errors.

Comment: @nicolaib I see you figured out, just want to point that the error you are getting, like probably other errors, as you say is because the elements aren't loaded yet, to avoid this my recommendation is to load your scripts at the end of the html body, just before the `</body>` close body tag.

Answer (score 1):

Using a proper `table` tag with `caption`, `tr`, `td` etc is important for accessibility users.
The dropzone library can be modified to better support a table (i.e having a template that starts with a `<tr>` tag).

Rewrite the Dropzone.createElement function (so it uses `tbody` block element instead of `div` block element if template is a `tr`):

```
// Fix the createElement so it works with tables
// Creates an element from string
Dropzone.createElement = function(string){
  var ele = document.createElement(string.startsWith("<tr") ? "tbody" : "div");
  ele.innerHTML = string;
  return ele.childNodes[0];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue, and the answer from wallek876 sent me in the right direction, so it will be the accepted answer.

The detail in the answer, that solved it, was that I saw that the `dropzone-previews` was on the outer of the table instead of at the bottom, where the new element should be added.

**Solution:**

I moved the `upload-container`  as an id to the `<div class="div-table" id="upload-container">` like so.

I kept the `<div id="preview-template">` as suggested and applied the `<div class="div-tr">` as the first child of the `previewTemplate`. This structure gave the table layout back and the rest of the styling was applied using CSS.

I didn't manage to put the previewTemplate in the HTML.